# A method's description doesn't show up in another class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, xml-documentation

I'm trying to add a description to my method, but it only shows up inside the original static class.

**Example:**

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns A + B
/// </summary>
/// <param name="A"></param>  
/// <param name="B"></param>
/// <returns></returns>

public static int Add(int A, int B)
{
     return A + B;
}
```

***Before this is marked as a "duplicate", I want to make everything clear: I'm not asking how to add a description.*** I'm having an issue that no similar answer has solved yet.

**Problem:**

The description only shows up when its method is called inside their original static class library.
I added a reference to the resulting DLL in my main program and when I hover my mouse over the Add() method, no description shows up, like I had never written one in the first place. Yet, the default VS 2013 functions still have their descriptions in them even when they came from a DLL.

Am I missing something? Is it a bug?

P.S. Yes, the DLL was created after the description was already added. As far as I know, it *should* show up...

Comment: Have you tried putting your cursor at the end of the method and pressing `Ctrl+Space` or `Ctrl+Shift+Space`? Hovering doesn't show any documentation for any methods for me, whereas using Intellisense shows the summary. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2887830/545680)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849672/how-to-show-method-parameter-tooltip-in-c

Comment: @Bringer128 I was asking because Visual Studio's default methods always show their descriptions and even exceptions (if they have any) whenever I hover my mouse over them. Example: Num.ToString() and it shows me what ToString() does if I hover my mouse over it (sometimes it shows me a message like "Documentation cache is being created. Please wait" or something similar, but the description shows a little while after that). That's at least in my case.

Comment: I use Resharper personally - I can press `Ctrl+Shift+F1` to see the full documentation. Did using the Intellisense pop up work?

Comment: @Bringer128 I pressed all of those shortcuts. No documentation has popped up. I just... don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently just went through adding descriptions to DLL's for use in other programs, and I'm pretty sure if you're using the DLL in another solution you need to have the accompanying XML file in the same folder(as the DLL) to get the descriptions working.

Comment: My Visual Studio only creates the DLL, not a XML file.

Comment: I found where the option to create XML files was by looking through my project's settings. One would think that VS should be clever enough to simplify it... 

If you hadn't tell about me about the XML, I would still be screaming at my laptop. Thank you.

Comment: No worries, glad I could be of help to you.